# Using AccountManager for Basic Authentication requests

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-volley, accountmanager, android-authenticator

I have a server which is not under my control. This is using basic authentication for user logins and subsequent requests.

I want to store the user credentials with the AccountManager framework and sync with the server using a content provider. However, I don't know how to create an Authenticator which is usable for Basic Authentication.

How do I create a request (say with Volley or kSoap2) using a custom Authenticator?